# Filter de tipo Object Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Basciamente quiero lograr hacer un `filter` de un `ListAdapter`, pero mi `ArrayList` es de tipo `Object`.

Tiene dos tipos de ítems, uno es titulo y el otro es un tipo `String` sin mas.

Lo único que quiero lograr es filtrar solo los títulos dejando los `Strings` sin tocar pero no lo logro conseguir.

Obviamente este `filter` va acompañado de un `EditText` como para hacer de barra buscadora.

Código del `Filter`:

```
 @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            if(constraint!=null && constraint.length()>0){

                constraint=constraint.toString().toUpperCase();

            ArrayList<Object> filter = new ArrayList<>();


            for(int i = 0; i<tempArrayTitulo.size();i++) {

if(((titulo)tempArrayTitulo.get(i)).getTituloTitulo().toUpperCase().contains(constraint)) {

titulo Titulo = new titulo(((titulo) tempArrayTitulo.get(i)).getnTitulo(), ((titulo) tempArrayTitulo.get(i)).getTituloTitulo());
                        filter.add(Titulo);

                     }if(((String)tempArray.get(i)).toUpperCase().contains("LIBRO")){
filter.add(tempArray.get(i));

                }
  return results;
```

Y en el `Publish` igualo el resultado del `filter` a el `originalArray`, por lo que básicamente si no agrego a los ítem de tipo `String` en el `filter` me quedo sin ellos luego de filtrar alguna palabra.

```
  @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            originalArray=(ArrayList<Object>)results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que a la instancia originalArray le estas cambiando la referencia del objeto, lo que tendrías que hacer es conservar la misma referencia, limpiar los elementos que tiene y agregar los nuevo elementos.

```
originalArray.clear();  //limpiar la lista original
originalArray.addAll(results.values); // agregar los nuevos elementos
notifyDataSetChanged(); // notificar al adapter de los cambios
```

Comment: Basicamente el filter como lo tengo funciona bien siempre y cuando le filtre un solo tipo especifico de objeto pero cuando queiro hacerlo con los dos en el mismo filter, no puedo

Comment: Basicamente el resultado que me da con el filter como lo tengo es que cada vez que lo utilizo me muestra vacio como si no encontrara nada, lo cual me resulta raro porque cuando hago exactamente lo mismo pero hago que el ArrayList sea solo de tipo <titulo> funciona perfecto pero cuando lo hago con tipo <object> para filtrat tanto los tipo titulo como los tipo string no me funciona para nada

Comment: El problema en realidad en solo filtrar los tipo titulo es que pierdo la referencia de los tipo string, es decir si se lo agrego despues de cada filtro pierdo el orden.  Por lo que se me ocurrio fue primero antes de cada filtrado que encuentre los tipo string y los cambie por un item titulo pero con un nombre especicifo para que despues de cada filtrado exitoso vuelva a cambia todos los titulos con ese nombre especifico a el tipo string. removiendo exactamente en esa posicion del array e insertando nuevamente el string en esa posicion,pero si bien funciona bastante bien va todo muy lento.

Answer (score 0):

La solucion esta en usar un instanceof, es lo mas eficiente y me funciona a perfeccion

if(tempArray.get(i) instanceOf Titulo){

} else {

}